# Manually load JQuery without triggering Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to debug or modify webpages from time to time using JQuery. I open Developer Tools, in Console enter

```
(function()
{
  var s=document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
  s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
  jQuery.noConflict();
})();
```

But Chrome says

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'".

I understand Content Security Policy is good to prevent cross site scripting. But I want to be able to load JQuery.

How can I load JQuery to any page?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74456654/816213

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override content security policy while including script in browser JS console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323631/how-to-override-content-security-policy-while-including-script-in-browser-js-con)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pasting loading code into console, you can just paste complete minified source code of jQuery.

Comment: I did in the same way afther I posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the page has that CSP directive, you can't (on a browser that supports the CSP); the page owner has it locked down. If it's a page you're really supposed to be debugging, modify the server to not send the CSP header or to allow scripts from `https://code.jquery.com`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem states: I need to debug or modify webpages from time to time using JQuery

There is an easier way to do that than trying to load it manually. This is what I typically do.  Try chrome's Jquery injector
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-injector/indebdooekgjhkncmgbkeopjebofdoid?hl=en