# Sahi sign in to mailtrap.io issue

Tags: ssl, gui-testing, sahi

I'm having an issue with Sahi Open Source logging into Mailtrap.io

the script is quite simple:

```
_navigateTo("https://mailtrap.io/");
_setValue(_textbox("email"), "emailHere");
_setValue(_password("user_password"), "passHere");
_click(_submit("Log in"));
```

however only first line of code executes.. as soon as I reach mailtrap.io then controller looses grip on html... In case I launch new browser from Sahi Dashboard and navigate to mailtrap.io, then Controller window is not coming up on Alt+doubleClick..

I added SSL cert. Anyone had this issue before? Anyone successfully using sahi with mailtrap?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work i think.

First I installed Sahi OS 5.0 and opened the firefox browser. With the SSL Manager I added security exceptions for sahi.example.com and mailtrap.io

On navigation to mailtrap I got an error:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource

This is a browserfeature and can be turned off in the about:config https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324485/1359903

Now the script runs and the controller can access the sites elements. I hope this works for you too.

Regards
globalworming