# Disabling "Content Security Policy" in CEF / CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp for off-screen rendering of web pages and I would like to execute a JavaScript code before taking a screenshot of the rendered page.

Using `browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.body.scrollHeight")` on some webpages (for example https://github.com/) unfortunately results in the following error:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets-cdn.github.com".

@ undefined:0:-1
```

This apparently happens because of the Content Security Policy header.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323631/how-to-override-content-security-policy-while-including-script-in-browser-js-con), it is possible to disable the security in Firefox. Is it also possible to disable it in CEF? Or is it possible to execute scripts in any other way?

Comment: You'll probably have to conduct your own research on this one, in theory you can modify the `headers` and modify the `CSP` (Removing them may also be an option). See http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10334&p=19338#p19338

Comment: You can also try some command line switches. 
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

CEF supports them too.

Comment: It's important to note that `CEF` only implements a subset of those command line switches. You'd have to check the source to see if a particular one was implemented.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm still running into this issue. The weird thing is you can run `eval` on the console, so it should be possible to disable CSP for certain scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never found a solution to this problem, I did not need to use it in the end. In case you solve the problem, feel free to post a solution and I will accept it for sure!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran throught the same problem, using cefsharp to test some javascript code on websites I don't own. Recent cefsharp version refused to process such requests, using ExecuteJavascriptAsync().

I solved my problem the brutal way, using a proxy to disable the CSP check.
The proxy replaces the meta tag http-equiv="content-security-policy" with a dummy one in order to disable it. Note that I didn't change the string length to avoid side effects such as changing "Content-Length" http headers.

The proxy: https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy

Here you can find my quick and dirty code.

The code to start the proxy:

```
        var proxyServer = new ProxyServer();

        var explicitEndPoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8123, true)
        {
        };

        // An explicit endpoint is where the client knows about the existence of a proxy
        // So client sends request in a proxy friendly manner
        proxyServer.AddEndPoint(explicitEndPoint);
        proxyServer.Start();
```

The proxyServer.BeforeResponse event:

```
    private async Task Proxy_BeforeResponse(object sender, Titanium.Web.Proxy.EventArguments.SessionEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.HttpClient.Response.Headers.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Type"))
        {
            if (e.HttpClient.Response.Headers.Headers["Content-Type"].Value.Contains("text/html"))
            {
                    string bodyString = await e.GetResponseBodyAsString();
                    e.SetResponseBodyString(bodyString.Replace("content-security-policy", "content-unsecure-policy"));
            }
        }
    }
```

The cefsharp switch to use the proxy:

```
cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "http://localhost:8123");
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSP restrictions only apply if you evaluate your script, if you simply execute JavaScript then the restrictions don't apply.
You can use ExecuteJavaScriptAsync.
If you need to return a value, you can use
     `GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("myregistredObject.retVal(document.body.scrollHeight)");`

`retVal` must accept the appropriate type of either string or int.

Comment: Actually this approach don't work if you try to inject code in a link that implement CSP.