# Include a third-party library as a content script without violating CSP & Intercepting headers

Tags: content-security-policy, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently writing a browser extension that supports Manifest-v2 and v3 which requires the CashJS library (lightweight version of JQuery) for convenience. I would like my content script `content/index.js` to be able to use this library `content/cash.min.js` but I get a CSP violation stating:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-wThdlNeRf1Fp3UGuX3Ch9caqVJ8S7Wn41fdlaVxsRDE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Here is my manifest.json (for v3):

```json
...
"content_scripts": [{
    ...
    "js": [
        "content/cash.min.js",
        "content/index.js"
    ]
}],
...
```

I have tried using `content_security_policy` in various ways (hashes & enabling `unsafe-inline`) but Chrome refuses it:

```json
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-wThdlNeRf1Fp3UGuX3Ch9caqVJ8S7Wn41fdlaVxsRDE='; object-src 'self';"
```

It gives the error `Invalid value for 'content_security_policy'.` when attempting to load the extension. I have read [this page from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) as well as other posts discussing this issue but haven't found a solution that fits my needs.

[This article from Chrome's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/contentSecurityPolicy/) mentions using their `sandboxing` feature but it only seems to work for webpages, not the scripts themselves.

I really don't want to intercept the headers as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323631/how-to-override-content-security-policy-while-including-script-in-browser-js-con).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't use this library as it's not compatible with extensions. Its `evalScripts` function creates a script element in the current web page, which means the code runs in [page context](/a/9517879), not in the context of the content scripts, even if you correctly relax the CSP (note that in ManifestV3 this key is an object, not a plain string, see the migration guide).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense thank you! Can you suggest an alternative?